# Application crashes on start in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make a dropdown effect with an ImageViews but when I try to run the app in the emulator, it gives me the "Unfortunately app has stopped." I am following an android studio course and the person in the course does not have any problems with using the images and I am using the same images as his

**EDIT**

**I am using the legacy grid layout and there are 9 ImageView's that don't have a src and the onClick method sets the image Resource to red.png in drawables**

### MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.connect3game;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void dropIn (View view) {

        ImageView marker = (ImageView) view;

        marker.setTranslationX(-1000f);

        marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

        marker.animate().translationX(1000f).setDuration(1500);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tLeft"
            android:layout_width="138dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="0"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tMiddle"
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="0"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tRight"
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bRight"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bMiddle"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bLeft"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mRight"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="2"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mMiddle"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_row="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mLeft"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_row="1" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Error Log

```
2022-09-29 22:10:30.544 3425-3425/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.connect3game, PID: 3425
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.connect3game/com.example.connect3game.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.connect3game:drawable/board" (7f070058)  is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f070058 a=-1 r=0x7f070058}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2441)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:493)
        at androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:272)
        at androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:710) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at com.example.connect3game.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Can you please add the error to your post

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. FWIW, I cover that topic in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Comment: Ok I added the Error log stack that i think is associated with this error

Comment: It reads `Error inflating class androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`.

Comment: .. caused by "Resource "com.example.connect3game:drawable/board" (7f070058)  is not a Drawable (color or path)". Your `@drawable/board` is not a [drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource)

Comment: The error clearly says `Resource "drawable/board" is not a Drawable (color or path)`. Whatever you put in that file has an error. As the error says, a drawwable file has to be either a static color or an svg file, declared with a <path> tag in it's xml.

Comment: i used the board.png as a background for the gridLayout, is that what is causing the error?

Comment: can you please help me i don't know how to fix this